# Updating Send Classification using API or ssjs

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, ssjs

Anyone has updated Send Classification(Name and External Key) using API or SSJS?

If someone can give some tips on this, would be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There are SSJS Core functions around Send Classifications. You can check them out [**here**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_sendClassificationFunctions.htm).

There are the following options:

- Add
- Remove
- Retrieve
- Update

For update, check [**here**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_sendClassificationUpdate.htm) for full details.

Here is an example:

```javascript
var sc = SendClassification.Init('mySendClassification');

var updatedSC = {
    Name : "Updated Send Classification",
    SenderProfileKey : "mySPKey",
    DeliveryProfileKey : "myDPKey"
};

var status = sc.Update(updatedSC);
```

There also is a SOAP API Object for Send Classifications that can be found **[here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/sendclassification.htm)**.

Here is a sample Create request:

```xml
      <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Options/>
         <Objects xsi:type="ns1:SendClassification" xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <CustomerKey>SendClass_1</CustomerKey>
            <Name>mySC</Name>
             <Client>
                <ID>123456</ID>
             </Client>
             <SenderProfile>
               <CustomerKey>mySC</CustomerKey>
             </SenderProfile>
             <DeliveryProfile>
               <CustomerKey>myDP</CustomerKey>
             </DeliveryProfile>
             <SendClassificationType>{{Type}}</SendClassificationType>
         </Objects>
      </CreateRequest>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try and let you know, if this was helpful for reaching my end goal. :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it to work thanks to the research by Gortonington in answer one. 
SenderProfile and DeliveryProfiles are mandatory fields to write the UpdateRequest for a Send Classification. To spare everyone else this fun exercise, here is a working example.

POST against your

{{SOAPEndpoint/}}Service.asmx

to perform updates using SOAP API and the CustomerKeys for the relevant objects:

Headers

```
Content-Type: text/xml
SOAPAction: "Update"
```

Payload:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <SOAP-ENV:Header>
            <fueloauth>{{accessToken}}</fueloauth>
        </SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
                <Options/>
                <Objects xsi:type="SendClassification">
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <CustomerKey>159</CustomerKey>
                    <SenderProfile>
                        <CustomerKey>89</CustomerKey> <!-- mandatory-->
                    </SenderProfile>  
                    <DeliveryProfile>
                        <CustomerKey>Default</CustomerKey> <!-- mandatory-->
                    </DeliveryProfile> 
                    <Name>new Name</Name>
                </Objects>
            </UpdateRequest>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Retrieving a send classification is easier:

Same endpoint

Headers

```
Content-Type: text/xml
SOAPAction: "Retrieve"
```

Payload:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{accessToken}}</fueloauth>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Options>
        </Options>
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>SendClassification</ObjectType>
            <Properties>ObjectID</Properties>
            <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
            <!--<Filter xsi:type="ns1:SimpleFilterPart" xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
               <Property>Name</Property>
               <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
               <Value>name of my Send Classification</Value>
            </Filter>-->
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

This will get you all Send Classifications.
Uncomment the filter part to find a specific one e.g. by name.